# Undefined variable: productImageBase

Tags: magento2.2, product-images, magento-community

I have this issue when I click on a category: Undefined variable: productImageBase...product/list.phtml on line 208.

Any idea?

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data');
$_aHelper = $this->helper('MGS\AjaxCart\Helper\Data');

$colClassRow = $themeHelper->getColClass();
$arrColClass = explode(' ', $colClassRow);
$pageType = 'catalogsearch';
$settings = $themeHelper->getThemeSettings();
$lazyLoad = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/general/lazy_load');
$baseImage = $this->getViewFileUrl('MGS_Mpanel::images/blank.png');
$baseImageHover = $this->getViewFileUrl('MGS_Mpanel::images/blank.png');
$perrow = $settings['catalog']['per_row'];
$animationType = $_aHelper->getConfig('ajaxcart/additional/animation_type');


$changeProductPerRow = $themeHelper->getEnableChangeProductPerRow();

if($this->hasData('page_type')){
    $pageType = $this->getData('page_type');
}
if($pageType == 'catalog'){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    if($category->getPerRow()){
        $perrow = $category->getPerRow();
    }
}elseif($pageType == 'catalogsearch') {
    if($settings['catalogsearch']['per_row']){
        $perrow = $settings['catalogsearch']['per_row'];
    }
}elseif($pageType == 'catalog_brand') {
    if($settings['catalog_brand']['per_row']){
        $perrow = $settings['catalog_brand']['per_row'];
    }
}

$hover_effect = "";
if ($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/disable_hover_effect')== 1){
    $hover_effect = "disable_hover_effect";
}

$colCheck = $themeHelper->convertPerRowtoCol($perrow);
$colClass = $themeHelper->convertColClass($colCheck, 'col');

$classNumber = '';
$dataCol = '';
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="category-product-actions">
        <?php if($changeProductPerRow): ?>
        <div class="change-product-per-row button-group layout-mode-button-group">
            <!-- <a href="#" class="pr two" data-col="6"></a>
            <a href="#" class="pr three" data-col="4"></a>
            <a href="#" class="pr four active is-checked" data-col="3"></a>
            <a href="#" class="pr six" data-col="2"></a> -->
            <?php $defaultValueProduct = $themeHelper->getDefaultValueNumberProductPerRow();
            if($defaultValueProduct == null) {
                $defaultValueProduct = '4';
            }
            ?>
            <?php $arrayValues = $themeHelper->getValuesNumberProductPerRow();?>
            <?php foreach ($arrayValues as $number): ?>
                <?php 
                switch ($number) {
                    case '1':
                        $classNumber = 'one';
                        $dataCol = '12';
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        $classNumber = 'two';
                        $dataCol = '6';
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        $classNumber = 'three';
                        $dataCol = '4';
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        $classNumber = 'four';
                        $dataCol = '3';
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        $classNumber = 'five';
                        $dataCol = '5';
                        break;
                    case '6':
                        $classNumber = 'six';
                        $dataCol = '2';
                        break;
                    case '7':
                        $classNumber = 'seven';
                        $dataCol = '7';
                        break;
                    case '8':
                        $classNumber = 'eight';
                        $dataCol = '8';
                        break;

                    default:
                        $classNumber = 'four';
                        $dataCol = '3';
                        break;
                }
                ?>
                <a href="#" class="pr <?php echo $classNumber; if($number == $defaultValueProduct) echo " active is-checked";?>" data-col="<?php echo $dataCol; ?>"></a>

            <?php endforeach;?>

        </div>
            <?php if(in_array($defaultValueProduct, $arrayValues)): ?>
                <?php 
                $colCheck = $themeHelper->convertPerRowtoCol($defaultValueProduct);
                $colClass = $themeHelper->convertColClass($colCheck, 'col');
                ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <div class="filter-toggle">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="title">
                <span class="icon pe-7s-edit"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $image_hover = 'product_thumbnail_image';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $image_hover = 'product_thumbnail_image';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>" id="product-wrapper">
        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <ol class="products <?php if ($changeProductPerRow): ?>product-list-masonry-change-product<?php endif ?> list items product-items <?php if ($block->getMode() == 'grid'): ?>row<?php endif ?> <?php echo 'row-'.$arrColClass[0] ?>">

            <?php $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image'); ?>
            <?php $size = $themeHelper->getImageSize(); ?>
            <?php $padding = $themeHelper->getImagePadding(); ?>
            <?php $quickViewHelper = $this->helper('MGS\QuickView\Helper\Data'); ?>
            <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare'); ?>

            <?php if ($block->getMode() == 'grid'): ?>
                <?php $params = $block->getRequest()->getParams();  ?>
                <?php if($settings['catalog']['ajaxscroll']): ?>

                    <?php if(isset($params['product_list_limit'])): ?>
                        <?php $countAll = $params['product_list_limit']; ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $countAll = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page'); ?>        
                    <?php endif ?>

                    <?php if(isset($params['p'])): ?>
                        <?php $i = ($params['p'] - 1) * $countAll; ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $i = 0; ?>
                    <?php endif ?>

                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php $i = 0; ?>
                <?php endif ?>

                <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
                <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): $i++; ?>
                    <li class="item product <?php if ($changeProductPerRow): ?>product-item-masonry<?php endif ?> product-item-info product-item <?php echo $colClass ?> <?php echo $themeHelper->getClearClass($perrow, $i) ?> <?php echo $hover_effect ?>">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <?php $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->resize($size['width'], $size['height'])->getUrl(); ?>
                        <?php $productImageHover = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image_hover)->resize($size['width'], $size['height'])->getUrl(); ?>
                        <?php if(!$lazyLoad): ?>
                            <?php $baseImage = $productImage ?>
                            <?php $baseImageHover = $productImageHover ?>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <div class="product-top">
                            <?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/images_slides')== 1): ?>
                               <div class="owl-carousel list_gallery">
                                    <a href="<?php  echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" style="padding-bottom: <?php echo $padding ?>;"  tabindex="-1">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $productImageBase ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="img-responsive product-image-photo img-thumbnail"/>
                                    </a>
                                   <?php if(basename($_product->getData('thumbnail')) != basename($_product->getData('image'))): ?>
                                       <a href="<?php  echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" style="padding-bottom: <?php echo $padding ?>;"  tabindex="-1">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $productThumbnail ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="img-responsive product-image-photo img-thumbnail" data-src="<?php echo $productThumbnail ?>"/>
                                       </a>
                                   <?php endif;?>

                                  <?php if((basename($_product->getData('small_image')) != basename($_product->getData('image'))) && (basename($_product->getData('small_image')) != basename($_product->getData('thumbnail')))): ?>
                                        <a href="<?php  echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" style="padding-bottom: <?php echo $padding ?>;"  tabindex="-1">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $productImageSmall ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="img-responsive product-image-photo img-thumbnail" data-src="<?php echo $productImageSmall ?>"/>
                                       </a>
                                   <?php endif;?>

                                </div>

                            <?php else:?>
                             <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" style="padding-bottom: <?php echo $padding; ?>;" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                                <img src="<?php echo $baseImage ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="img-responsive product-image-photo img-thumbnail<?php if($lazyLoad): ?> lazy<?php endif ?>" data-src="<?php echo $productImage ?>"/>

                                <?php if(basename($_product->getData('thumbnail')) !=  'no_selection'): ?>
                                    <?php if(basename($_product->getData('thumbnail')) != basename($_product->getData('small_image'))): ?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $baseImageHover ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="img-responsive img-hover-show<?php if($lazyLoad): ?> lazy<?php endif ?>" data-src="<?php echo $productImageHover ?>" />
                                    <?php endif ?>
                                <?php endif ?>

                                <div class="product-image-photo"></div>
                            </a>

                            <?php endif;?>
                            <?php echo $themeHelper->getProductLabel($_product) ?>
                            <ul class="actions-link" data-role="add-to-links">

                                <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><?php echo $quickViewHelper->aroundQuickViewHtml($_product); ?></li>

                                <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && !$settings['catalog']['wishlist_button']): ?>
                                    <li><button data-title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                       class="action towishlist"
                                       title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                       aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                       data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                       data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                       role="button">
                                        <i class="pe-7s-like"></i>
                                    </button></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if(!$settings['catalog']['compare_button']): ?>
                                    <li><button data-title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       class="action tocompare"
                                       title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                       role="button">
                                        <i class="pe-7s-graph3"></i>
                                    </button></li>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php if ($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/disable_add_to_cart') == 0 && $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/disable_hover_effect') == 0): ?>
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <div>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/add', ['uenc'=>$postParams['data']['uenc'], 'product'=>$postParams['data']['product']]); ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['uenc']; ?>">
                                            <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>" />
                                            <?php 
                                                $has_option = 0;
                                                if($_product->getTypeId() == 'simple'){
                                                    $data = $_product->getData();
                                                    $has_option = ( isset($data['has_options']) && $data['has_options'] == 1) ? 1 : 0;
                                                }


                                             ?>
                                            <?php if($animationType == 'cartshow' && ($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable' || $_product->getTypeId() == 'bundle' || $_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped' || ($_product->getTypeId() == 'simple' && $has_option == 1) )): ?>
                                                <button class="action btn-cart tocart" type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>'">
                                                    <span class="icon pe-7s-shopbag"></span>
                                                    <span class="product-item-link">
                                                        <?php echo __('Add to cart'); ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </button>   
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <button class="action tocart btn-cart" type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                    <span class="icon pe-7s-shopbag"></span>
                                                    <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            <?php endif ?>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product details product-item-details">
                            <h5 class="product name product-item-name">
                                <a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                                </a>
                            </h5>

                            <?php if(!$themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/review')): ?>
                                <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType,true); ?>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

                            <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>
                            <?php if ($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/disable_add_to_cart') == 0 && $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/disable_hover_effect') == 1): ?>
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <div>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/add', ['uenc'=>$postParams['data']['uenc'], 'product'=>$postParams['data']['product']]); ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['uenc']; ?>">
                                            <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>" />
                                            <button class="action tocart btn-cart hover_effect" type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                <span class="icon pe-7s-shopbag"></span>
                                                <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
                <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <?php $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->resize($size['width'], $size['height'])->getUrl(); ?>
                    <?php $productImageHover = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image_hover)->resize($size['width'], $size['height'])->getUrl(); ?>
                    <?php if(!$lazyLoad): ?>
                        <?php $baseImage = $productImage ?>
                        <?php $baseImageHover = $productImageHover ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <li class="item product product-item-info product-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="product-image-content">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" style="padding-bottom: <?php echo $padding; ?>;" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $baseImage ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="img-responsive product-image-photo img-thumbnail<?php if($lazyLoad): ?> lazy<?php endif ?>" data-src="<?php echo $productImage ?>"/>

                                        <?php if(basename($_product->getData('thumbnail')) !=  'no_selection'): ?>
                                            <?php if(basename($_product->getData('thumbnail')) != basename($_product->getData('small_image'))): ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo $baseImageHover ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="img-responsive img-hover-show<?php if($lazyLoad): ?> lazy<?php endif ?>" data-src="<?php echo $productImageHover ?>" />
                                            <?php endif ?>
                                        <?php endif ?>
                                        <div class="product-image-photo"></div>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php echo $themeHelper->getProductLabel($_product) ?>
                                    <?php echo $quickViewHelper->aroundQuickViewHtml($_product); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="visible-xs padding-top20"></div>
                                <div class="product details product-item-details">

                                    <h5 class="product name product-item-name">
                                        <a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                            <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </h5>

                                    <?php if(!$themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/review')): ?>
                                        <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType,true); ?>
                                    <?php endif ?>

                                    <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

                                    <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>

                                    <?php if($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description')): ?>
                                        <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif ?>

                                    <ul class="actions-link" data-role="add-to-links">

                                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                            <li><?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                            <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/add', ['uenc'=>$postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED], 'product'=>$postParams['data']['product']]); ?>" method="post">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                                <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>

                                                <?php 
                                                $has_option = 0;
                                                if($_product->getTypeId() == 'simple'){
                                                    $data = $_product->getData();
                                                    $has_option = ( isset($data['has_options']) && $data['has_options'] == 1) ? 1 : 0;
                                                }




                                             ?>
                                            <?php if($animationType == 'cartshow' && ($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable' || $_product->getTypeId() == 'bundle' || $_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped' || ($_product->getTypeId() == 'simple' && $has_option == 1) )): ?>
                                                <button class="action btn-cart tocart" type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>'">
                                                    <span class="icon pe-7s-shopbag"></span>
                                                    <span class="product-item-link">
                                                        <?php echo __('Add to cart'); ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </button>   
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <button class="action tocart btn-cart" type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                    <span class="icon pe-7s-shopbag"></span>
                                                    <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            <?php endif ?>
                                            </form></li>
                                        <?php endif ?>

                                        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && !$settings['catalog']['wishlist_button']): ?>
                                            <li><button data-title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               class="action towishlist"
                                               title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                               data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                               role="button">
                                                <i class="pe-7s-like"></i>
                                            </button></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <?php if(!$settings['catalog']['compare_button']): ?>
                                            <li><button data-title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                               class="action tocompare"
                                               title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                               aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                               data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                               role="button">
                                                <i class="pe-7s-graph3"></i>
                                            </button></li>
                                        <?php endif ?>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-pagination<?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/ajaxscroll')): ?> ajaxscroll-enable<?php endif ?>">
        <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<script>
    require([
    'jquery',
    'waypoints'
], function(jQuery){
    (function($) {
        $('.filter-toggle .title').click(function(){
            $('html').toggleClass('filter-open');
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs([ 
        'require',
        'jquery', 
        'mgsmasonry',
        'mgsvisible'
    ], function( require, $, Masonry) {
        require( [ 'bridget' ], function( jQueryBridget ) {
            jQueryBridget( 'masonry', Masonry, $ );
            $(window).load(function() {
                var $container = $('.product-list-masonry-change-product').masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.product-item-masonry',
                    columnWidth: '.product-item-masonry',
                    horizontalOrder: true
                });
                $('.layout-mode-button-group').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
                  // change layout mode
                    $container.masonry({
                        columnWidth: '.product-item-masonry',
                        maxHeight: 0
                    });
                });  

                // change is-checked class on buttons
                $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
                  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
                  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'a', function() {
                    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
                    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
                  });
                });
            });  
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                var $container = $('.product-list-masonry-change-product').masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.product-item-masonry',
                    columnWidth: '.product-item-masonry',
                    horizontalOrder: true
                });
                $('.layout-mode-button-group').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
                  // change layout mode
                    $container.masonry({
                        columnWidth: '.product-item-masonry',
                        maxHeight: 0
                    });
                });  

                // change is-checked class on buttons
                $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
                  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
                  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'a', function() {
                    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
                    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
                  });
                });
            });  
        });

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            $(".product-list-masonry-change-product > .product-item-masonry").each(function(){
                if($(this).visible(true,true,'vertical')) {
                    $(this).addClass('enable');
                }else {
                    $(this).removeClass('enable');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: share your list.phtml code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$productImageBase` is used in line 208 but is not defined in the file.

It's a bit unclear what this variable should be, which of the images. But a quick fix is probably replacing it with `$productImage`

Answer (score 0):

Please use isset(productImageBase) condition in your list file. if this solution work please accept it. Thanks